# CSS percentage and pixel layout combined

Tags: html, css

I'm really struggling with this, if anyone could help my eternal thanks goes out to you.

I have a CSS DIV with a width of 1260px called wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
width: 1260px;
}
```

Inside this wrapper DIV I have three DIVs called column-left, column-mid, and column-right:

```
#column-left {
width: 245px;
float: left;
}

#column-mid {
width: 55.55555555555556%; /* (700px/1260px) */
float:left
margin-left: 35px;
margin-right: 35px;
}

#column-right {
width: 245px;
float:left;
}
```

Very simply, it is a three column layout within a wrapper div. The middle div "column-mid" has a percentage width set. It should be 700px wide which is 55.55555555555556% of 1260px (the width of the wrapper div).

It all looks fine at this resolution. However if I change the width of the wrapper div to say 1400px, then the column-mid div is not expanding to fill the space properly. It's equivalent width is only increasing to 775px when really it should be filling 794px because 794px is 55.55555555555556% of 1430px

Why is the column-mid div only going up to 775px? What I am trying to achieve is that the left and right columns stay a fixed size (245px) but the middle column should increase in relation to the size of the wrapper div.

Comment: Those are really weird resolutions. Could you explain why you would want a percentage of 55.555555556%, because for a site those resolutions are usually not acceptable. Everything needs to fit on the site without side scrolling. Use proper resolutions that handle proper percentages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Er8uX/2/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1260px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#column-left {
    width: 245px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
}

#column-mid {
    margin: 0 280px;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}

#column-right {
    width: 245px;
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```

I think this is what you want, basically: fixed left and right column, main content according to wrapper width. I've used absolute positioning to keep them in place; on the right one I've used 100% height if you have a column with a background and want it to run all the way down, the left one has height according to content.

Comment: This is great. The padding is slightly confusing me, I'm used to margins to create space. But if it works, it works!

Comment: `margin` works just as well, right? I agree, using `margin` is more correct. What to use mainly depends on what your layout looks like.

Comment: This has worked out really well, but I am also having trouble getting the percentages to translate correctly into pixels. Would you be so kind as look at my edit in the question and give your opinion on what is wrong with the calculation?

Comment: I tend to stay away from percentages; they are very hard to get right, because you have to take into account things like padding and borders on practically every element involved. This is most surely the cause of your 'missing pixels'.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because you are not changing `width` of `#column-left` and `#column-right` according to whole width and just changing `width` of `#column-mid`.

For the case where `width` of `#column-left` and `#column-right` to remain `245px` and `width` of `#column-mid` to be responsive,

try this:

```
#column-mid {
    width: calc(100% - 560px); //245px for #column-left, 245px for #column-right and 70px for margin
}
```

Another solution:

Try:

```
#wrapper {
    display:table;
}
#column-left,#column-mid,#column-right{
    display:table-cell;
}
#column-left,#column-right{
    width: 245px;background:#f7f7f7;
}
#column-mid {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0 35px;//for spacing
}
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Er8uX/3/)

Comment: But I have to take into account the 35px margin on either side. So would it be calc(100% - 560px) ?

Comment: Note that this is IE9 and up only: http://caniuse.com/calc . That said media queries would be acceptable fallbacks

Comment: @Paulie_D yes in that case, width of all columns should be in percent.

Comment: I can't use calc due to the browser compatibility. I have to support as far back as IE7. Just to clarify I don't want the widths of the left and right columns to change ever. They should always be fixed. Only the middle column should expand to take up the remaining space.

Comment: @volumeone I have edited answer. hope it solves your problem.

Comment: New answer is very elegant. Perhaps even cleaner than kasimir's solution which is also working. Not sure which one to go with now!

Comment: Perhaps elegant, but I feel `display: table` and such should be used for table-like elements, not basic site layout/structure. Furthermore, `display: table-cell` is not supported by IE7 (http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3Atable-cell) so that's not good enough for your level of support.

Comment: Yes I suppose you're right. We got rid of tables for layout, but now using CSS to emulate a table layout again.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Hiral. I tried out both yours and kasimir's solutions and overall kasimir's was better for my design. In Dreamweaver it doesn't seem to handle displaying CSS table/table-cells very well so my design was all over the place. Kasimir's works and displays correctly for me so voted as answer.