# Make relative positioned div contain all child divs that are absolute positioned

Tags: css

**Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nN5Td/**

I have a basic layout of two side bars and a "maincontent" div that are all wrapped up in a "wrapper" div. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="aside-left">
        <ul>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
            <li>Link3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <p>All content goes in here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="aside-right">
        <ul>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
            <li>Link3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    min-height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
#aside-left {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
#maincontent {
    margin: 0 130px;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
#aside-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
```

I put borders on everything so that you can see the issue.

The `#wrapper` div does not contain the absolute positioned `#aside-left` and `#aside-right` divs. Why are these sidebar divs absolutely positioned? Because the `#maincontent` div grows in size horizontally/fluidly depending on the user's resolution while the sidebars stay the same size. (If you want to know more here's my original layout question [CSS percentage and pixel layout combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634559/css-percentage-and-pixel-layout-combined))

What can I do to ensure that the layout does not break (that is, having a fluid `#maincontent` centre div with fixed left & right sidebars) but have the `#wrapper` adjust in height to contain all the elements? I would like to avoid Javascript if possible.

Is there anything similar to 'clearfix' to make relative positioned container adjust to the height of absolute position divs? I cannot know the height of my absolute positioned divs because their content is dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at your problem and this seems to work: **http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/3/**.

Basically, I moved your two columns to the #maincontent, so they can flow along with the "actual content".

Then to split the columns from the content itself I put the content inside of a div element.

To ensure the #maincontent adjusts in height to the content, I then added a div with style="clear:both" an so the #maincontent and #wrapper got stretched in height to the columns/content height.

Here is your tweaked HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">   
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="aside-left">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div id="aside-right">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
        <div id="content">
            <p>All content goes in here.</p>
        </div>  
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your tweaked CSS's:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
#aside-left {
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
#maincontent {
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
    width:100%;
}
#maincontent #content{
    margin:0 130px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#aside-right {
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
```

Try it, and let me know if it was useful.

Regards.

Comment: wow thank you so much, it works! this is a far better layout structure than I had before and now allows the container to grow vertically in line with its child divs. really brilliant!

Comment: I've added a div to the #content area but its causing a major clear problem. Can you please advise why? heres the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/4/

Comment: Remore clear:both and margin top from the rectangle box.